# ¿Cómo reemplazo los valores de una tupla en un bucle sin definir las variables?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Estoy tratando de no escribir varias veces un código utilizando un bucle for y reemplazando los valores de las tuplas en el ciclo for, pero antes he añadido los valores en una tupla:

```
dimensiones_c=[altura_c, longitud_c, profundiad_c]
dimensiones_t=[altura_t, longitud_t, profundiad_t]
dimensiones_l=[altura_l, longitud_l, profundiad_l]


t_dimensiones=[dicmensiones_c, dimensiones_t, dimensiones_l]


for i in t_dimensiones:
    for j in i:
        j=float(input(f'Ingrese la altura de su {}: '))
        j=float(input(f'Ingrese la longitud de su {}: '))
        j=float(input(f'Ingrese la profundidad de su {}: '))
```

¿Cómo puedo corregir esto y además en esta parte del código `float(input(f'Ingrese la altura de su {#Columna, trabe o losa}: '` determinar y añadir si es una columna, trabe o losa?

Me disculpo por preguntar tanto y no formular todo en una pregunta, pero me surgen las dudas con forme avanzo. Agradezco mucho su apoyo y muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de nada, cuando metes los datos en una estructura con `[]` se trata de una  [lista](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), las [tuplas](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) se definen con `()`.

Una manera de que introducir las tres dimensiones para los tres tipos de elementos, puede ser almacenarlas en un [diccionario](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
dimensiones = {'Columna': [], 'Trabe': [], 'Losa': []}
datos = ['altura', 'longitud', 'profundidad']

for tipo in dimensiones:
    for dato in datos:
        dimensiones[tipo].append(float(input(f'Ingrese la {dato} de su {tipo}: ')))

print(dimensiones)
```

En este caso pedirá los siguientes datos a introducir (he añadido dimensiones de prueba para que veas la salida que tendrías):

```
Ingrese la altura de su Columna: 1
Ingrese la longitud de su Columna: 2
Ingrese la profundidad de su Columna: 3
Ingrese la altura de su Trabe: 4
Ingrese la longitud de su Trabe: 5
Ingrese la profundidad de su Trabe: 6
Ingrese la altura de su Losa: 7
Ingrese la longitud de su Losa: 8
Ingrese la profundidad de su Losa: 9

{'Columna': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 'Trabe': [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], 'Losa': [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]}
```

**Aclaración:**

En respuesta a tu comentario, te aclaro la manera de acceder a los valores almacenados en el diccionario.

Para acceder por ejemplo a `Columna`, pondrías:

```
`print(dimensiones['Columna'])`
# Te devolvería la lista [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Las operaciones puedes hacerlas como en cualquier lista, por ejemplo:

```
print(sum(dimensiones['Trabe']))
# Te devolvería 6.0
```

Puedes hacer otras operaciones (esta no es la mejor manera, pero te sirve para ver cómo acceder a cada elemento de la lista):

```
vol_losa = dimensiones['Losa'][0]*dimensiones['Losa'][1]*dimensiones['Losa'][2]
print(vol_losa)
# Te devolvería 504.0
```

**Posible mejora**

He visto en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/450096/c%C3%B3mo-multiplico-los-valores-almacenados-en-una-lista-dentro-de-una-funci%C3%B3n) para qué querías multiplicar las dimensiones de los diferentes elementos. Si te sirve de ayuda, puedes aprovechar los bucles en los que solicitas la información para directamente calcular el valor de la multiplicación de estos, en vez de tener que crear la función `multiply`.

Aunque en velocidad no vas a ganar prácticamente nada ya que son bucles muy pequeños, reducir el código si que te va a ayudar a leerlo mejor, sobre todo si tienes que modificar algo en el futuro.

Podría quedar así:

```
for tipo in dimensiones:
    multip = 1
    for dato in datos:
        valor = float(input(f'Ingrese la {dato} de su {tipo}: '))
        dimensiones[tipo].append(valor)
        multip *= valor
    print(f'{multip:.2f}')
```

Comment: Una duda, ¿cómo evalúo o cómo opero (multiplico, sumo, divido, etc) los valores que se almacenaron dentro de la tupla que están en los diccionarios? Ejemplo: 1*2*3=6, 4*5*6=120 y 7*8*9=504

Answer (score 1):

**Código**:

```
dimensiones = []
tipo = input("Introduzca columna, trabe o losa: ")
dimensiones.append(float(input(f"Ingrese la altura de su {tipo}: ")))
dimensiones.append(float(input(f"Ingrese la longitud de su {tipo}: ")))
dimensiones.append(float(input(f"Ingrese la profundidad de su {tipo}: ")))
print(f"Las dimensiones de su {tipo} son:", dimensiones)
```

**Explicación**:

Se pide al usuario que introduzca "columna", "trabe" o "losa". A continuación se pide la altura, longitud y profundidad y estos valores se guardan en la lista `dimensiones`.

Según el primer valor introducido, se imprime un resultado u otro.

**Resultado**:

```
Introduzca columna, trabe o losa: columna
Ingrese la altura de su columna: 2.5
Ingrese la longitud de su columna: 3.2
Ingrese la profundidad de su columna: 4.7
Las dimensiones de su columna son: [2.5, 3.2, 4.7]
```