# ¿Cómo multiplico los valores almacenados en una lista dentro de una función?

Tags: python

He almacenado los valores que el usuario ingresa por consola en una lista para luego usar dichos valores en una función y hacerlos operadores aritméticos. El problema surge cuando llamo a la lista para que sea utilizada para realizar las operaciones aritméticas, me arroja este error: **TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'**.

Primero se realiza esta parte:

```
dimensiones = {'Columna': [], 'Trabe': [], 'Losa': []}
datos = ['altura', 'longitud', 'profundidad']

result=[] #Aquí se almacenan los valores que se multiplican en la función "multiply" durante el bucle

for tipo in dimensiones:
    for dato in datos:
        dimensiones[tipo].append(float(input(f'Ingrese la {dato} de su {tipo}: ')))
   
    def multiply(numbers):  
        total = 1
        for i in numbers:
            total *= i  
        return total  
    print("{0:.2f}".format(multiply((dimensiones[tipo]))))
    result.append("{0:.2f}".format(multiply((dimensiones[tipo]))))
    print(result)
```

Una vez almacenados y el flujo de ejecución vaya hacia abajo realizo lo siguiente:

```
for materiales in elementos:
    print(materiales)
    pesos, bolsas = calculo(materiales, result)#Aquí está el problema, me arroja el error que expliqué arriba
```

Aquí dejo el código completo:

```
dimensiones = {'Columna': [], 'Trabe': [], 'Losa': []}
datos = ['altura', 'longitud', 'profundidad']

result=[]

for tipo in dimensiones:
    for dato in datos:
        dimensiones[tipo].append(float(input(f'Ingrese la {dato} de su {tipo}: ')))
   
    def multiply(numbers):  
        total = 1
        for i in numbers:
            total *= i  
        return total  
    print("{0:.2f}".format(multiply((dimensiones[tipo]))))
    result.append("{0:.2f}".format(multiply((dimensiones[tipo]))))
print(result)
    #print(sum(dimensiones[tipo]))

mat_columnas = dict(
    cemento=350 * 1.05,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=180,
    cal=68) 
mat_trabes = dict(
    cemento=350 * 1.05,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=200,
    cal=68) 
mat_losas = dict(
    cemento=350 * 1.05,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=180,
    cal=68)     

def calculo(materiales, volumen):
    peso_individual = {key: volumen * value for key, value in materiales.items()}
    bolsas = (peso_individual["cemento"] / 50)
    return peso_individual, bolsas

elementos = [mat_columnas, mat_trabes, mat_losas]
for materiales in elementos:
    print(materiales)
    pesos, bolsas = calculo(materiales, result)
    print(f' {pesos}', 'Bolsas de cemento: '"{0:.4f}".format(bolsas) + '\n')
```

Hay alguna forma de corregir esto? Agradezco bastante su apoyo. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error te está diciendo que estás intentando multiplicar una secuencia (que podría ser una lista) por un número de punto flotante.

Este error se debe a la siguiente línea de la función `calculo()`:

```
    peso_individual = {key: volumen * value for key, value in materiales.items()}
```

En el momento en que esa línea se ejecuta, la variable `materiales` tiene algo como lo siguiente:

```
# materiales
{'cemento': 367.5, 'arena': 0.56, 'grava': 0.84, 'agua': 180, 'cal': 68}
```

por lo que la variable `value` dentro de la comprensión irá tomando valores de tipo `float`  correspondientes 367.5, 0.56, etc...

Sin embargo la variable `volumen` tiene algo como lo siguiente (los números dependerán de las respuestas del usuario a las preguntas iniciales):

```
# volumen
['60.00', '120.00', '210.00']
```

Como vemos se trata de una lista, por lo que al intentar `volumen*valores` tenemos ya el error de tratar de multiplicar una secuencia por un float.

Entiendo que lo que ocurre es que `volumen` **no debería recibir una lista** sino directamente un número (por ejemplo 60.00)

En este caso el error proviene de este bucle que hay al final de tu código:

```
elementos = [mat_columnas, mat_trabes, mat_losas]
for materiales in elementos:
    print(materiales)
    pesos, bolsas = calculo(materiales, result)
    print(f' {pesos}', 'Bolsas de cemento: '"{0:.4f}".format(bolsas) + '\n')
```

Aquí es donde estás llamando a `calculo()` y le estás pasando una lista como segundo parámetro. Supongo que lo que en realidad querías hacer es pasarle un solo elemento de esa lista, uno diferente en cada iteración del bucle.

Esto puede hacerse de la forma siguiente:

```
elementos = [mat_columnas, mat_trabes, mat_losas]
for materiales, vol in zip(elementos, result):         # <--- zip
    print(materiales)
    pesos, bolsas = calculo(materiales, float(vol))    # <--- vol es un elemento
    print(f' {pesos}', 'Bolsas de cemento: '"{0:.4f}".format(bolsas) + '\n')
```

La función `zip()` empareja elementos de dos iterables, así en cada iteración obtendrás una pareja `materiales, vol` donde `materiales` ha sido extraido de la lista `elementos` mientras que `vol` ha sido extraido de la lista `result`.

Comment: Pero volvería a lo de antes al eliminar `.format` (que no puse explícitamente en la pregunta, perdón) pero no puedo iterar `result` dentro de `pesos, bolsas = calculo(materiales, result)`, en este caso cómo lo puedo iterar para los 3 resultados distintos almacenados en esa lista?

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez Quizás comprendí mal lo que se intenta calcular en ese código (ya que realmente no lo explicas en la pregunta). He ampliado la respuesta con otra posible interpretación, que creo que es la correcta. Si me confirmas que esta es la interpretación buena, edito la respuesta para quitar la otra y dejarlo todo más claro.

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia, es exactamente lo que quería hacer. En estos temas de ingeniería civil si calculo mal por un detalle algo, podría ser fatal. Saludos!

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez Ok, pues he editado la respuesta para eliminar toda la parte previa que no hacía lo que querías, y así dejar el tema más claro y la respuesta más corta.